# Firebase admin SDK how to list users by creation time

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have not found [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) showing this to be possible however the firebase auth console allows you to order by creation time so it must be possible.

I have > 1M users so fetching all and then ordering is not an option.

I am using the node admin sdk for Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only public API for getting the list of users from Firebase Authentication is in the Admin SDK, and indeed does not allow you to request the data in a specific order or to filter the data that is returned.

The Firebase console uses an undocumented API endpoint, that you should not call in your own code - as it may change at any time.

Comment: Thanks Frank. My intended use is to write a local script that checks firebase auth users against our own database as a way to verify that account creation is atomic. I wouldn't be depnding on that API. Is it publicly accessible?

Comment: Any thoughts on this Frank? I'd like to know if it's a publicly accessible API. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following up, would love to know what is used to sort by creation time. Even Firefoo is able to sort auth users by creation time.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase console does not necessarily use the Firebase Admin API to source its data.  It could be using something private.

The [listUsers API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthlistusers) doesn't have any options for sorting.  If you want this feature, maybe reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to request it.

Normally what developers do is not depend on that list API for sorting and instead use their own database.  That gives them the flexibility to store whatever they want per user, then sort and organize it any way they want.